# Bootstrap arrow that's attached to div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very very new to bootstrap and front-end frameworks in general. But, I am able to notice the characteristics that sites that use bootstrap have in common. The following picture contains something that I find to be very ubiquitous amongst bootstrap sites. The downward (or any direction) blue arrow that's pointing the the text below it is what I'm referring too.

I used firebug to inspect the elements and found it to be something that was relevant to the `.hero-unit` div.

How exactly does this work and how is it accomplished?

[image: Downward arrow]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't come standard with bootstrap but [Here is a good article](http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles) on how to do with `:after` which I believe is what you are looking for.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/e53UH/4/)

```
.hero:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    content:'';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 10px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 10px transparent;
    border-right: solid 10px transparent;
}
```

You make the triangle larger and smaller by adjusting the `border-*` attributes, and also the margin-left(border * -1).

Comment: If .hero has the gradient background, is it possible to make arrow to be the same background with .hero?

Comment: what about arrow come before div, have tried to change it to .here:before but no luck, please help

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you found in firebug. Hero Unit does refer to a jumbotron-style header, a large header element that can be used in bootstrap. You can find this element here:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#typography

Still the arrow you are referring to seems to be something that has been designed by the developer and does not come with the bootstrap unit.