# little point on reaction block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see on [this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/user-comment-example) link there is en block with a little point on the left side
I was wondering if there is not just a class to make a block with a little point on the left. Without using css? just like `class="img-circle"` for example where it makes it round.

[this pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2i4w.png)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/20963059/6429700

Comment: Can you elaborate .... maybe mark the the block...

Comment: @לבנימלכה eddited it

Comment: @thattommm show my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="triangle">here we talk!!</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.triangle{
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
color: white;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}


.triangle:after{
position: absolute;
left:-10px;
top: 18px;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-right: solid 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
border-top: solid 10px transparent;
}
```

**Explain:** 
in the `div` you create the square in css I define it...
in `:after` I defined the triangle
If you want to change the background color you have to change both of them

Comment: If you wnt to change the sizes... try to change it in F12 in real time runing  it will be easier...

Comment: @thattommm -- is it helpfull?

Comment: happy to help ;)

Comment: Maybe you can look at my other question? if you want